# Find a coordinate to make a vector perpendicular to other

Tags: vectors, mathematical-physics, angle

I have two vectors $(2,5,7)$ and $(-1,x,3)$. I need to select an $x$ in a way that the second vector will be perpendicular to first.
The angle of two vectors is described as $cos(\phi)=\frac{a \cdot b}{|a|\cdot|b|}$, so $cos90°=0$.

$$0=\frac{5x-19}{\sqrt {78} \cdot \sqrt {10+x^2}} = 5x \cdot \sqrt {780+78x^2}-19\cdot \sqrt {780+78x^2}=\sqrt {780+78x^2}\cdot(5x-19);$$

So whether  $\sqrt {780+78x^2}=0$ or $(5x-19)=0$. Since $\sqrt {780+78x^2} \neq 0$, $x = \frac{19}{2} = 3\frac{4}{5}$.

But if I try to use it in the vector $(-1,x,3)$ it's gonna produce an angle around $29°$ between the two vectors.

So, any suggestions to solve it?

Comment: Recall: $x\bot y \iff x\cdot y=0$ where $\cdot$ is the usual inner product. You are overcomplicating things

Comment: Note that neither vector is zero vector. So Just look at the numerator and that should be zero.

Comment: $-2 + 5 x + 21$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated above two vectors are perpendicular if $$\cos(\phi) = \frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{|a||b|}=0,$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Note that, if $|a|,|b|\neq 0$, this is equivalent to $\langle a, b\rangle=0$. In your example you get
$$\langle a,b \rangle = 2*(-1)+5*x+3*7.$$
Inserting this in the above condition and solving for $x$ will provide the solution $x=-\frac{19}{5}$.

I think you just miscalculated in the calculation of the scalar product and when you solved $5x+19=0$.